# Do we need to test a failure scenario of a public method which fails with an Exception?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest, scalamock

I have a case class `Employee`
defined as `case class Employee(.........fields.....)`
I have a method say

```
def getEmployees(organization: String): Future[Seq[Employee]] = {
   val result = employeeClient.getAllEmployees(organization)

   // some logic on this list of Employees received from the 
   client and manipulate it to get  finalListOfEmployees and return it 
   to caller of `getEmployees`//

  finalListOfEmployees

//end //
}
```

Now I test `getEmployees` using scala mock. I am not handling exception coming from `getEmployees` or not `recovering` from it. That means Exception appearing at `getAllEmployees` of client method will be traveling back to the caller of `getEmployees`.

Now the question is do we need to test this aspect ?

I meant does the following test add any value ??

```
"Fail with future" in {  (mockEmployeeClient.getAllEmployees_).expects("SomeOrganization").returning(Future.failed(new Exception("failed"))
          getEmployees("SomeOrganization).failed.futureValue.getMessage shouldBe "failed"
}
```

Comment: I've never been fan of mocks because you're just not testing anything here.

Comment: The more tests you do the more cases you cover, the better your application is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we should test it because the semantics here seem to be the callers of `getEmployees` expect failures to be represented by a failed `Future`. Now consider what would happen if someone would refactor `getEmployees` such that the failures in `employeeClient.getAllEmployees(organization)` are recovered by returning an empty list `Future(Nil)` instead like so

```
def getEmployees(organization: String): Future[Seq[Employee]] = {
 val result = employeeClient.getAllEmployees(organization)
 result.recover { case e => List.empty[Employee] }
 ...
}
```

Everything would compile fine like before, but suddenly the semantics are quite different. A unit test could catch this change in semantics, and prompt us to either remove the refactoring or update callers of `getEmployees` appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you are using scala because you want to use functional programming, it is better to handling error cases in a more functional way, for example wrapping the call to getAllEmployees with a Try monad. 
Apart from that, the tests must cover all possibles scenarios of the application to ensure that your program will behave properly in that situation. So, if this exception can occur, it should be tested too, te same way as any other output